# PyQT4 and Threading: Closing MainWidget after QThread finished and ListWidget updated

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to understand how threading works in Python. Therefore I wrote an application that is installing some packages in a separate QThread.

Once the worker is finished (finished Signal emitted), I'd like to wait a few seconds and then Close the MainWidget (see below):

```python
def finished(self):
        self.installbutton.setEnabled(True)
        self.listwidget.addItem(QtCore.QString("Process complete, have a nice day!"))
        time.sleep(5)
        self.close()
```

The Problem seems now, that calling self.close within the finished-callback leads to a Situation where the ListWidget is no more updated anymore before the window closes.

My guess is, that the ListWidget and the callback function live in the same stack and therefore the ListWidget has no Chance to terminate any more. But how to solve these kind of issues?

Any suggestions how I can overcome this?

By the way: I'm "forced" to use Python 2.7.5 and PyQt4 in order to be compliant with the rest of my Company... that's why I'm using the old-style signals

Here the code:

```python
import sys
import os
import time

import subprocess
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = InstallWizzard()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



class InstallWizzard(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)

        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.thread = Worker()

        hlayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.listwidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.installbutton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.installbutton.setText("Install Brother now...")

        hlayout.addWidget(self.installbutton)


        self.listwidget.addItem(QtCore.QString(r'Click "Install Brother now... to start installation"'))
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(hlayout)

        self.connect(self.installbutton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"),self._on_installation_start)
        self.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("finished()"), self.finished)
        # self.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("terminated()"), self.updateUI)
        self.connect(self.thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("install_mssg(QString)"), self._cmd_processed)

        hlayout.addWidget(self.listwidget)


    def _cmd_processed(self, mssg):
        self.listwidget.addItem(QtCore.QString(mssg))


    def _on_installation_start(self):

        self.installbutton.setEnabled(False)

        cmds = [("Installing comtypes", r'easy_install comtypes')]
        self.thread.install(cmds)


    def finished(self):
        self.installbutton.setEnabled(True)
        self.listwidget.addItem(QtCore.QString("Process complete, have a nice day!"))
        time.sleep(5)
        self.close()


class Worker(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):

        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self,parent)
        print("Started Worker...")


    def install(self, cmds):
        self.cmds = cmds
        self.start()


    def run(self):

        for desc, cmd in self.cmds:
            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("install_mssg(QString)"),QtCore.QString(desc + ": ..."))
            try:
                self._write_cmd_line(cmd)
                mssg = "... Successful"
            except Exception as e:
                mssg = QtCore.QString(str("... Faillure: " + e))

            self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("install_mssg(QString)"),mssg)

        print("ond tschuss from worker")


    def __del__(self):

        self.quit()
        self.wait()


    def _write_cmd_line(self, cmd):
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        a,b = p.communicate()
        if "cannot" in a or "error" in a or "not recognized" in a:
                errormssg = "Could not proccess cmd!"
                logging.error(errormssg)
                raise Exception(errormssg)

        else:
            logging.debug(str(cmd) + " successful")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you're trying to learn about multithreading in python, I would recommend not looking to PyQt QThreading first. This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies specifically the post by philshem

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Thanks for your reply:)
I already know this post. Most of these examples seem pretty much the same (likewise QT Tutorials).

But I cannot make a combination to enable the implementation I need.

So if you had a concrete advice to my problem, would be very helpful. Also if you knew of any tutorial addressing the need of having a gui- and a worker thread in the same application.

Thanks!

Comment: I found this helpful: https://joplaete.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/threading-with-pyqt4/

Answer (score 0):

after reading your question and your code.. in understand that you have two thread the main thread and worker thread and when you're worker is done(I mean here that thread is reached the last line of your code) you want to notify the main thread to close the worker and switch to another window(Probably) or do something else.

TODO this obviously you need to communicate with the UI thread(MainThread), so you'll need to add this lines in your **Worker(Thread) Class**

```
signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str) # Create a signal
```

then go to the last line from your thread, and be sure that when your worker reach that line the job will be done, and add this line to notify the main thread

```
self.signal.emit('Some String here') # this will send the string over the signal to your UI thread
```

Now **Jump To Your InstallWizzard Class ** and add this lines 
inside your __init__ method add this line below **self.thread = Worker()**

```
self.thread.signal.connect(self.finished) # finished is a method inside your class
```

Now inside Your finished method you can terminate/close/quit you're method easily using something like that

```
self.thread.quit() # as you might guessed this will quit your thread.
```

also you can replace quit() with terminate() if you want to force the worker to be closed please but please read this warning From the Qt documentation for QThread::terminate:

> **Warning:** This function is dangerous and its use is discouraged. The
>   thread can be terminated at any point in its code path. Threads can be
>   terminated while modifying data. There is no chance for the thread to
>   clean up after itself, unlock any held mutexes, etc. In short, use
>   this function only if absolutely necessary.

and if you care about the string which it will be sent over signal from the Worker add new parameter to you finished method to get access to the string.
and this is it :)

I know that I am too late to answer your question(1 years ago ) but it might be helpful for other developers...anyway cheers

Comment: You're always Welcome :)